# Viva Connections - Asking authentication for Power Apps WebPart/SPFx failing to call MS Graph

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams

We are building an intranet for a customer, and on some pages, there are custom-built SPFx WebParts that make calls to Microsoft Graph, and some Power Apps added using the out-of-the-box Power Apps WebPart. For both cases, it works perfectly when opening the pages from SharePoint, or adding the page as a Teams tab (SharePoint pages option).

However, from Viva Connections, the pages work perfectly on the first load time. And then start to fail most of the times.

Graph calls from SPFx WebParts fail...

Power Apps webpart prompts to sign:

[image: Prompt]

Using the Teams dev tools to identify the traffic it simply seems no auth token is being passed in both cases. As the same pages/WebParts work fine from

SharePoint and Teams tabs, my understanding is that the issue relates to something on Viva Connections.

Has someone had this issue? Any advice?